# GCMBroadcastreceiver not called if receive sms from non-app Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

I made android application that can sms and call to app and non-app(GSM or other phone number). If I send sms from app to app, GCMBroadcastreceiver is called, but if I send sms from GSM to my app, GCMBroadcastreceiver not called, here is my code :

GCMBroadcastreceiver.java :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = GcmBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "receive wakeful broadcast");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        //setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

}
```

GcmIntentService.java :

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    private static final String TAG = GcmIntentService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 2;

    private long[] vibratePattern = {
            0, 500, 500, 500
    };

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private AddressBookManager addressBookManager;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
        addressBookManager = AddressBookManager.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

        Intent messageIntent = new Intent(this, GetMessageService.class);
        startService(messageIntent);

        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
        Log.d(TAG, "messageType: " + messageType);
        if(!extras.isEmpty()){
            Log.d(TAG, "2.extras: " + extras);
            if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)){

            }

            if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)){

            }

            if(GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)){
                String extrasMessage = extras.getString("message");
                Log.d(TAG, "message: " + extrasMessage);

                if (extrasMessage!=null){
                    try {
                        JSONArray arrayJson = new JSONArray(extrasMessage);
                        if (arrayJson!=null){
                            for(int i = 0; i < arrayJson.length(); i++){
                                JSONObject json = arrayJson.getJSONObject(i);
                                String type = json.getString("type");
                                String from = json.getString("from");
                                String message = json.getString("message");
                                sendNotification(type, from, message);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //Google Cloud Messaging Data is null
                    //sendNotification(null, null, null);
                }

            }
        }       

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String type, String msisdn, String message){
        String title = msisdn;
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_message_man);

        if(addressBookManager.hasUser(msisdn)){
            User user = addressBookManager.getUser(msisdn);

            if(!StringUtil.isEmpty(user.getContact().displayName)){
                title = user.getContact().displayName;
            }

            if(!StringUtil.isEmpty(user.getContact().photoThumbUri)){
                try {
                    bitmap = Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(user.getContact().photoThumbUri));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(!StringUtil.isEmpty(user.getAvatarFile())){
                Bitmap fileBitmap = ImageTools.readFromFile(user.getAvatarFile());
                if(fileBitmap != null){
                    bitmap = fileBitmap;
                }
            }
        }

        if("multi_sender".equals(type)){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_message_multi);                                 
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
        .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setVibrate(vibratePattern)
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentText(message);       

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, ConversationActivity.class);
        char c = msisdn.charAt(0);
        if (msisdn.startsWith("+") || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')|| (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || msisdn.startsWith("0")) {
            resultIntent.putExtra("msisdn", msisdn);
        }
        else {
            //Tambah + di depan msisdn agar sama dengan msisdn di MessageActivity (History Message bisa dipanggil)
            String msisdns = "+"+msisdn;
            resultIntent.putExtra("msisdn", msisdns);
        }

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());       
    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
<!-- receivers -->
        <receiver
            android:name=".gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.marlinmedia.tkitalk" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!-- services -->
        <service android:name=".gcm.GcmIntentService" />
```

is there something wrong with my code or something else ?

Comment: Could you clarify how you are sending the sms messages?

Comment: I send sms using android application that I made using linphone library, if I send using app to app the notification is showed, but if I send sms from phone (not from my app) using gsm number to my app, the notification not showed

Answer (score 0):

You can directly send SMS from your app to another app without using GCM. The architecture of GCM is made to send push notification over the internet through the GCM server.

You can make use of the ***SMS Manager*** and the following permission to send SMS from one app to another.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

For more details take a look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_sms.htm).